# Find most-depicted Wikidata items that have no image

Tags: wikidata, sparql, wikimedia-commons, wikibase

Wikimedia Commons has a new feature where a picture can have metadata saying it depicts a given Wikidata item.

For instance, https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Grandpark_Plaza.jpg depicts https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q11303 (skyscraper).

My question: How to find the Wikidata items that:

- Are used as a "depicts" value by a lot of Wikimedia Commons files
- Do NOT have a [P18](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P18) (image) property

It is tricky because it involves two [Wikibase](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase) servers: Wikidata, and the Structured Data on Commons (SDoC)'s Wikibase server. I am open to any solution, SPARQL or not, hosted or not, open source or not.

Comment: There is a discussion at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons_talk:Structured_data#Find_most-depicted_Wikidata_items_that_have_no_image . The current consensus is "this is not possible yet", but I believe it is possible already, just not with a single SPARQL query, but rather with several API queries and a bit of manual processing.

Comment: seems to be some recent (May 2020) updates to your link: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Structured_data/Media_search and a demo (but still I don't know if you can cross-link to items without images)
https://tools.wmflabs.org/hay/sdsearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a federated query with the Wikimedia Commons endpoint and the Wikidata endpoint. The query below does take a while to complete - though.

```
SELECT 
  ?count
  ?depicted ?depictedLabel
  ?example_file
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT 
      (COUNT(*) AS ?count)
      ?depicted
      (SAMPLE(?file) AS ?example_file)
    WHERE {
      ?file wdt:P180 ?depicted .
    }
    GROUP BY ?depicted
    ORDER BY DESC(?count)
    LIMIT 100
  }
  SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
    MINUS { ?depicted wdt:P18 [] }
    OPTIONAL {?depicted rdfs:label ?depictedLabel FILTER (lang(?depictedLabel) = 'en') } .
  }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?count)
```

Short link: https://w.wiki/5MyH